# ckeditor causes comments prefixed by @ in subsequent scripts to be executed as code in IE 10

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, internet-explorer-10

I have an HTML page like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://svn.ckeditor.com/CKEditor/releases/latest/ckeditor_basic_source.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //@x=y
    </script>
</head>

<body>
Test Page
</body>
</html>
```

The comment `//@x=y` gets executed as code in IE 10 and the browser complains that `'y' is undefined`:

[image: minimal testcase]

The browser stops complaining if:

- I remove CKEditor script
- Remove the `@` character
- Change the order of `<script/>` tags

What could be going wrong here?

**UPDATE:** I narrowed down the root cause to a [conditional compilation statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/8ka90k2e%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) in CKEditor's [core/env.js](http://svn.ckeditor.com/CKEditor/releases/latest/_source/core/env.js) file.

```
if ( !CKEDITOR.env )
{
    /**
     * @namespace Environment and browser information.
     */
    CKEDITOR.env = (function()
    {
        var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        var opera = window.opera;

        var env =
        /** @lends CKEDITOR.env */
        {
            /**
             * Indicates that CKEditor is running on Internet Explorer.
             * @type Boolean
             * @example
             * if ( CKEDITOR.env.ie )
             *     alert( "I'm on IE!" );
             */
            ie      : /*@cc_on!@*/false,
...
```

If I remove that `/*@cc_on!@*/` comment, everything works fine as one would expect.

Comment: I get this warning on IE10 about loading scripts or ActiveX controls, and it requires me to click allow access for it to work.

Comment: My guess is it has something to do with the ckeditor doing `document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + CKEDITOR.getUrl( '_source/core/loader.js' ) + '"></script>');`

Comment: @BradM yes, that I think, loads the rest of the CK modules.

Comment: It appears as if the `@` becomes a comment terminator if it appears directly after `//` or `/*`. This is truly bizarre.

Comment: I have cross posted on CKEditor forums: http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/ckeditor-causes-comments-prefixed-by-in-subsequent-scripts-to-be-executed-as-code-in

Comment: Looks like the jQuery team has come across this issue before: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13274

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that this is caused by the conditional compilation statement included in CKEditor. If `/*@cc_on@*/` is set, IE10 recognizes the part following the `//@` as JavaScript code it should execute. The jQuery team encountered a variant of this bug [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13274). Wrapping the `//@` part in a block comment like `/*//@x=y*/` gets around the problem.

The CKEditor team has filed a [bug report](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10679) on this.